# dependency injection in a servlet 3.0 web app?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to write a servlet 3.0 web app, just to learn basic servlet handling. Normally i would use spring.

Now I have a servlet which access a DAO which queries the database. Now, what is the best way to instantiate that DAO and use it? My best guess would be to have a private property in the servlet and create an instance of the DAO when the servlet is created.

But, will the servlet be created multiple times?

Is there something similar to springs dependency injection available in servlet 3.0?

Comment: Also, if i have multiple servlets which all needs access to the dao, that would mean i create the dao multiple times. That just seems wrong! Offcourse i could have a service class between the servlet and the dao, but that woudl then need to be a singleton?

Comment: Can't you just use Spring for bean creation, but not use Spring's other features (e.g. URL mapping, etc.) and then call getBean() from your servlet code to get whatever beans you need?  (Or you could use it for dependency injection if you let it manage your servlet's creation/destruction lifecycle, but I'm guessing you don't want that.)  Or are you trying to build code as though you weren't allowed to use Spring at all?

Comment: Just to get a better understanding of the underlying features i'm trying to not use spring at all, that is correct:)

Answer (score 2):

EJB 3 dependency injection is extremely simple to use. A single annotation, @EJB, causes the injection of a declared bean. The injection of the SomeDAO bean into a Servlet 3.0 looks like this:

```
@WebServlet(name="Messenger", urlPatterns={"/Messenger"})
public class Messenger extends HttpServlet {    
    @EJB
    SomeDAO someDAO;
 }
```

The injected SomeDAO bean could be an interface or a no-interface view bean. As long as there is only one implementation of the interface, it will be injected without any ceremony.

Comment: Which dependency is needed to get the `@EJB` annotation? So far, I only have `javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar`.

Answer (score 2):

[javax.servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/package-frame.html) API is one of the technologies included in java-ee.

[CDI](http://cdi-spec.org/), is the Context and Dependency Injection technology in java-ee

So to answer your question, your use case could be solved by using only CDI and Servlets.

But most of the application servers that supports above (e.g. [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html), [Glassfish](https://glassfish.java.net/) webprofiles), will also support EJB (which uses cdi) and JPA. EJB+JPA can be used to implement DAOs.

Arjan Tijms has put together a nice link overview of what is [included and happening in the java-ee-7 world](https://javaee7.zeef.com/)